# Return values more than average (without using nested query)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question which asks me to display the mark of students who got more than the average, came up with:

```
SELECT Mark
FROM StudentMarks
HAVING Mark > AVG(Mark);
```

Unfortunately, this brings the error:

Your query does not include the specified expression "Mark" as part of an aggregate function
Is there any way to solve this without using:

```
SELECT Mark
FROM StudentMarks
WHERE Mark > (SELECT AVG(Mark) FROM StudentMarks);
```

i.e no nested query?
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: You could cross-join on that query instead, but I'm not sure that'd satisfy the "no subquery" requirement.

Comment: As a side note, the reason I do not want to use a sub-query is that 
1) Its hasnt been taught yet
2) This should be solved easily, but it somehow isn't

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Mark
From StudentMarks
GroupBy Mark
Having Mark > AVG(Mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery in the having statement.

```
Select Mark
From StudentMarks
Group By Mark
Having Mark > (select AVG(Mark) from StudentMarks);
```